# Making property of class in python

Tags: python

I'm studying the python cookbook.
I'm trying to execute the below code which is from the chapter 8 of the python cookbook.
This code is about properties of class

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        self.first_name=first_name  

    #getter function
    #property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name

    #settier function
    def first_name(self, value):  
        print(value, isinstance (value,str))
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("expected a string")
        self._first_name=value

    #deleter function
    def first_name(self):
        raise AttributeError("can not delete attribute")

    c=Person('PETTER')
    c.first_name(42)
```

After making the class, I made instance and I entered a wrong value on purpose.

I expected that I got the TypeError(expected a string).
But I didn't.
What part of my code should be changed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not SolveMyExerciseForMe.com

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot some pieces, specifically:

1. `@property` above the first `def first_name(self):`
2. `@first_name.setter` above `def first_name(self, value):`
3. `@first_name.deleter` above the second `def first_name(self):`

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you the error you expect.

Two major issues:

1. You had `self.first_name = first_name` in your `__init__`. This ends up overwriting the function `first_name`. You meant `self._first_name = ...`.
2. You defined the same function three times (`first_name`). Python doesn't have function overloading, so you can't do this. I believe the last definition wins. Below I commented out the two functions that I don't think you actually meant to call.
3. You had an indentation error... your two last lines probably weren't getting executed at all because they were inside your class definition.

"Working" code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        self._first_name = first_name

    #getter function
    #property
    # def first_name(self):
    #     return self._first_name

    #settier function
    def first_name(self, value):  
        print(value, isinstance (value,str))
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("expected a string")
        self._first_name=value

    #deleter function
    # def first_name(self):
    #     raise AttributeError("can not delete attribute")

c = Person('PETTER')
c.first_name(42)
```

**EDIT**

As other answers point out, based on the context of your question, you're probably about to make `first_name` an actual property via `@property` decorators. That's probably a better way to make your code work, but hopefully this helps you to understand what's happening in your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing decorate function with the **@property** and **@setter**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        self.first_name=first_name  


    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name

    @first_name.setter 
    def first_name(self, value):  
        print(value, isinstance (value,str))
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("expected a string")
        self._first_name=value
```

**property exapmle**

```
class Temp:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
```

for detail of [property in python](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)

Comment: @junghyemin wlcm